# Quasar / Vue q-table expanded rows export to csv

Tags: javascript, vue.js, export-to-csv, quasar-framework

I have a little table that shows an expanded row with additional data, and that is working well.

When I export this table to CSV, it only exports the main table with the data from the array.  The expanded-row information isn't exporting and I would love if it did.

This is my code... thanks for any help.

```
          <q-table 
            class="my-sticky-header-table"
            title="Maximum Run Values" 
            style="height: 600px"
            flat
            bordered
            v-model:pagination="pagination"
            v-model:selected="selectedSomething"
            :rows="this.countsArray2" 
            :columns="runCountsColumns"
            :loading="loading"
            row-key="keyForTable"
            no-data-label="There are no runs in this event."
            >
            <template v-slot:top-right>
              <q-btn
                color="primary"
                icon-right="archive"
                label="Export to csv"
                no-caps
                @click="exportCountsTable"
              />
            </template>

              <template v-slot:header="props">
                  <q-tr :props="props">
                    <q-th auto-width /> 
                    <q-th
                      v-for="col in props.cols"
                      :key="col.name"
                      :props="props"
                    >
                      {{ col.label }} 
                    </q-th>
                  </q-tr>
                </template> 

                <template v-slot:body="props">
                    <q-tr :props="props">
                      <q-td auto-width>
                      <q-btn size="sm" color="grey-10" round dense @click="props.expand = !props.expand" :icon="props.expand ? 'remove' : 'add'" />
                    </q-td>
                      <q-td key="trialNum" :props="props">{{ props.row.trialNum }}</q-td>
                      <q-td key="judge" :props="props">{{ props.row.judge }}</q-td> 
                      <q-td key="Class" :props="props">{{ props.row.Class }}</q-td>
                      <q-td key="numOfRuns" :props="props">{{ props.row.numOfRuns }}</q-td>
                    </q-tr>


                <q-tr v-show="props.expand" :props="props">
                <q-td colspan="100%">
                  <div class="text-left">
                     <q-table 
                      flat
                      bordered
                      dense
                      :rows="props.row.details" 
                      :columns="runCountsSubColumns"
                      row-key="pk_runs"
                      no-data-label="No Records"
                      :hide-bottom="hideBottom"
                      :hide-pagination="hidePagination"
                      :hide-selected-banner="hideSelectedBanner"
                      :hide-no-data="hideNoData"
                      :rows-per-page-options="[0]"
                     >
                      <template v-slot:header="props">
                        <q-tr :props="props" >
                          <q-th
                            v-for="col in props.cols"
                            :key="col.name"
                            :props="props"
                            class="text-italic text-black-12"
                          >
                            {{ col.label }} 
                          </q-th>
                        </q-tr>
                      </template> 

                      <template v-slot:body="props">
                        <q-tr :props="props">
                           <q-td auto-width dense key="novice" style="max-width: 40px; text-color: red" :props="props"><q-chip square color="grey-4"> {{ props.row.novice }}</q-chip></q-td>
                           <q-td auto-width dense key="advanced" style="max-width: 40px; text-color: red" :props="props"><q-chip square color="grey-4"> {{ props.row.advanced }}</q-chip></q-td>
                           <q-td auto-width dense key="excellent" style="max-width: 40px; text-color: red" :props="props"><q-chip square color="grey-4"> {{ props.row.excellent }}</q-chip></q-td>
                           <q-td auto-width dense key="master" style="max-width: 40px; text-color: red" :props="props"><q-chip square color="grey-4"> {{ props.row.master }}</q-chip></q-td>
                          </q-tr>
                      </template>

                     </q-table>
                  </div>
                </q-td>
              </q-tr>

                </template>

          </q-table>
```

This is my export javascript:

```
   async exportCountsTable() {
      console.log("exportCountsTable ", this.useJudgeName, this.countsArray2)
      // naive encoding to csv format
      const content = [this.runCountsColumns.map(col => wrapCsvValue(col.label))].concat(
        this.countsArray2.map(row => this.runCountsColumns.map(col => wrapCsvValue(
          typeof col.field === 'function'
            ? col.field(row)
            : row[ col.field === void 0 ? col.name : col.field ],
          col.format
        )).join(','))
      ).join('\r\n')

      const status = exportFile(
        'SW Run Counts Report ' + this.useJudgeName + '.csv',
        content,
        'text/csv'
      )

      if (status !== true) {
        $q.notify({
          message: 'Bthis.dogArrayer denied file download...',
          color: 'negative',
          icon: 'warning'
        })
        }

    }, // end exportCountsTable
```